I remember important parts of this movie but not the title?
I don’t think it was a movie that made it to the big screen. Possibly lifetime movie? 
I think it came out in the early 2000’s 
The movie was about a woman and her young daughter maybe 10 years old or so and the daughter tells her mom that a person they know killed her in her past life. It was either that or that she just knows about this woman who was murdered many years ago, before she was even born. She also identifies the woman in pictures in one scene if I’m rembering correctly.
The goal was to bring this murderer to justice.
Important parts were that they knew the murderer. Don’t remember how they’re connected to him but he might have been some sort of doctor or family friend perhaps.
The movie shows flash back scenes occasionally to the woman who was killed (supposedly the young girl’s past life)
I believe there was a scene where the little girl confronts the man who had murdered her in her past life and tells him that she’s the one who he had killed before. Not sure what their relationship was in her past life.
Again, in her past life she was an adult.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification.What time period was it showing?  Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title
